# Is there any way to noninvasively/invasively measure the current/voltage (Power) to get actual power consumed by load?

Tags: power, measurement, high-voltage

One of the application im working on needs three phase power measurement to be done through micro-controller. The power measurement is in the range of **90kVA**.
Is there any way to noninvasively/invasively measure the current/voltage to get actual power consumed by load(compressor in this case).

I want to understand a way to measure a Power consumption with a sensor and update data to server with IoT to remote server. micro-controller aspect here is peripheral and any WiFi module can be used to update data to server.

While referring to some material I did came across some methods as **Abraham electrostatic voltmeter** or **Transformer ratio method** and some other for voltage measurement.

[High Voltage Engineering - J R Lucas 2001](https://www.mrt.ac.lk/web/sites/default/files/elect/files/HV_Chap6.pdf)

But need to understand which method is used in commercial measuring instruments.
Also is it practically possible to keep any WiFi or RF node for data collection at its vicinity?

***Note**:I clearly understand the risk at these Power levels. Im here to understand the technology so that i can concentrate on my part of design.*

Comment: I think at these powers, the microcontroller aspect is peripheral – you're asking for noninvasive three phase power measurement sensors, right?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! KVA is not a voltage measurement unit but rahter apparent power. Also, if you need to ask about something that's 90 KVA, you need to seek professional help by someone certified.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, its pure electrical question, I just mentioned micro-controller to be specific about what output im expecting.

Comment: @winny  Sorry for the mistake, but its just flow of typing I was asking for voltage and then switch to VA and forgot to remove voltage. I hope you got my fillings.

Comment: As mention VA isn't VOLTAGE, it is POWER. Also it is lower k not upper K (K=Kelvin, k=kilo). now if you are dealing with 90kVA,, high chance this is 400Vac but this isn't "VERY HIGH" this is legally speaking LOW-VOLTAGE.  The uC is the least concern here. You need to know what you are measuring, the safety surrounding grounding. Do you have access to neutral or is a virtual star suitable. Then... simple case of high-resistance, buffer, ADC and isolators. I won't post more details because anything over 50Vac you should know and if you don't, you shouldn't be working on it

Comment: already done it @Tyler

Comment: At 90kVA you need a professional electrician...

Comment: @JonRB thank you for correcting again. I'm not EE pro. Question is very simple. uC is mentioned just to elaborate context, because if its not mentioned, there are people who will point out that also. Currently I only have info that its compressor which is acting as load and power is about max 90kVA that has to be measure. I need to create something to measure consumption that should challenge or compare on board power indicator panel.

Comment: so you are after VOLTAGE and CURRENT measurement. What voltage ? this will drive the current and voltage measurement scheme.

Comment: can you get away with 1watt meter method or do you need 3watt meter method.   You are jumping WAY too low-level to implementation when your  needs are not even understood let alone stated

Comment: _"Question is very simple"_ At 90 kVA, nothing is simple.

Comment: You can buy a wattmeter that has current sensors that clamp around insulated conductors. You will need access to individual conductors to do that. The instrument will need direct access to un-insulated terminals for the voltage connection. It is very likely that you can get such an instrument that will both display the results and transmit results data. Components are available for you to build such an instrument. You can find other questions here that cover various aspects of doing that. There are non-contact voltage sensors, but I doubt they are sufficiently accurate for a good wattmeter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because specific product recommendations are off topic and a general, "how can I build a wattmeter" question is too broad. In addition, it is not completely clear what is being asked.

Comment: Several companies sell ICs (and will sell you the Reference Design PCB) for AC power meters.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. While the question mark is lacking, "Is there any way to noninvasively measure the current/voltage to get actual power consumed by load" seems a clear and well-phrased formulation. While specific products are off-limits, general approaches are not.

Comment: I don't know about a good way, but when you build it I want to see it when you turn it on for the first time

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, non-contact power measurement is not possible. That is, you cannot make a device which will make no electrical connections to an isolated set of wires and determines the power being provided to the load.

Power (kVA) is the product of voltage and current. It is possible to make clamp-on current meters, which take advantage of the fact that AC current produces an AC magnetic field which can be sensed by, for instance, Hall effect sensors or a specially-constructed transformer. These are pretty standard devices, and come in a large range of scales.

Voltage, on the other hand, does not lend itself to non-contact measurement.

With that said, one might (in theory) build an AC power system with a built-in load (such as a resistor of known resistance), and it would be possible to do a non-contact measurement of the current in the load and thereby back out the voltage. But I doubt that this is what you're thinking of.

However, all of the above is pretty much beside the point. As others have commented, 90 kVA is nothing for someone with no experience to even think about messing with. Your question suggests that this is not a homework exercise, but rather a business situation. Based on what you have asked, I suggest very strongly that you tell your boss that he needs to hire either an experienced engineer or a consultant with a proven track record. I'm sure you'd rather not plead inexperience to your boss, but in this case it is very much the best option. A commercial high-power installation is not a good laboratory for self-education.

Comment: Dear @WhatRoughBeast, This is what i was expecting. As there is very less information I found through google, I came here expecting to get some knowledge. Its Obvious that I was not expecting a solution here. I understand there are other ways to get information. But look at this thread and see how its helpful for others. At least its helping me.

Comment: I understand from the beginning the seriousness and risk involved in this domain & at this voltage, but there is no way to show it in my question. Frankly speaking Im into IoT domain and Im no expert in Electrical and High Voltage area. My world revolves around 5v. Ive no boss... im the owner of small startup. Eventually I will improve my question as im slowly getting the details of this topic.

Answer (score 1):

To take a three-phase power measurement you need to measure the instantaneous voltages and currents so that you can calculate instantaneous power and integrate that value to measure energy consumption.

Current measurement can be done relatively safely by using split-core [Hall-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) sensors of which there are many types.

[image]

*Figure 1. Split-core Hall-effect sensors of which there are many types.*

These can be clamped on while the equipment is powered down and the signal wiring routed safely away from the mains and out to the energy meter.

Voltage measurement presents bigger challenges as it generally requires connection to the supply being monitored, requires proper fusing and isolation from the energy meter analog and logic circuitry. This would best be done by three small mains transformers but you may have trouble getting these at your required phase to phase voltage if there is no neutral available.

Since the compressor is most likely a balanced load you may be able to monitor one-phase only and multiply the energy consumption by three.

Go on over to the [Open Energy Monitor](http://openenergymonitor.org) project where most of this has been thrashed out already.

Comment: Thank you for info@Transistor, but we are talking about voltage up to 90kVA, does all above sensors will work the same way at this range?

Comment: 90 kVA isn't a voltage - it's a power measurement. This error suggests that you are missing some very fundamental understanding of your project. For current measurement you need a current sensor that will work in the range of **current** (**A**, not kVA) that your compressor uses.

Comment: word voltage is coming because I will also need to measure it to get Energy/Power consumed(correct me If Im wrong), while current is must and thats what we are discussing in all above post. I think Ive tried to clear my question above by making changes in it. If some mistake are made unknowingly should be ignored. You have also already mentioned about voltage in your answer.